# Why can't access my controller in Codeigniter when upload to hosting?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

I got below errors when I try to call some controller in Codeigniter.

I have upload my website to hosting and I also try to find the solution to edit

PHP.ini

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
 include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```

But it still not work for me moreover I also check on Routing and Configure it have something metter.
and that hosting let me change the version of PHP I try to change from old to newest version and PHP.ini but still the same

**Note:It it is good working at my Localhost;**

**What is my wrong configure or my codeing because I get this (ERROR - 11-30-14 13:01:35 --> 404 Page Not Found: register//index)** Where //index always add automatic after I type my controll name

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: include(application/views/errorshtml/error_404.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: core/Exceptions.php

Line Number: 169
```

And

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: include(): Failed opening 'application/views/errorshtml/error_404.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\php\includes')

Filename: core/Exceptions.php

Line Number: 169
```

How could I do?
Please help

Comment: make sure that you uploaded whole project on the server, sometimes ftp simply does not upload all files, edit your post and add .htaccess.

Comment: I've using file manager on hat hosting in that can  me generate .htaccsss, change the permission too

Comment: show generated .htaccess file (open in notepad or some kind of text editor)